# ubuntu 12.04 LTS nVidia driver mirrors second monitor

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have installed ubuntu 12.04,without nvidia driver I can use my Laptop screen and a second screen over the HDMI port of my laptop.

For some reason when I install the **nVidia driver 331.20** the second screen which is using the HDMI port is getting a mirrorscreen of my Laptop. The nVidia driver also doesn't recognize the second screen. But when I enter the ubuntu display setting it show both screen overlapping each other. When I try to put on screen beside the other one and click on apply, both screens turn black and I get logged out but both screens are still mirroring.

Anyone got a pointer for me how I could fix this? If any logs needed to better trace my Issue please tell me as I'm new to unix/linux.

E: My graphic card is a GT 630M

Comment: Have you tried / do you see the [`TwinView`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors) option?

Comment: Have you tried / do you see the [`TwinView`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors) option? ... Maybe it could help prod things further..?

Comment: Do you see a check box that says Mirror Displays?  Or have you checked Nvidia X Server Settings to see if Twinview is enabled, like nutty about natty said?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow

Comment: are you working with the repository driver or you had install the propertary (xyz.run)? I had experienced a lot of trouble with nvidia propertary and not so much improvements. you can try by installing arandr and manage the monitor from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  Look for Errors.

Also check out `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  `xorg.conf` used to be necessary for setting up X properly, but my experience has been that it usually gets in the way now.

I have a newer version of Ubuntu and a newer graphics card, but I run without any `xorg.conf` file and don't use the `nvidia-settings` tool at all any more.  Instead I can just use the standard displays applet.

If you must use `xorg.conf`, I find the displays applet only gets in the way.  In this case I suggest deleting the display config for your user and instead use the `nvidia-settings` as root to set the monitor config. Note that setting the monitors this way makes it a pain when docking and undocking a laptop.  Since you are using a laptop I highly suggest trying to run without `xorg.conf` defined (make sure to rename it instead of deleting it, so you can put it back if there is a problem).

Good luck